# Is there a good tool for finding references to properties from within the XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Studio is only really good at finding references between code. Is there a good way of seeing exactly where properties are mapped to XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use typed bindings, e.g.

```
<Window xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ...>
    ... 
    <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyNamespace:MyType}"> 
        ... <!-- The binding types inside this StackPanel are typed -->
    </StackPanel>
```

...then you can use "Find References" to find the property usages, do refactorings, etc...

I think that if you use ReSharper, the design time experience is even better...

Described here: https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/

Comment: Huh. I regularly create design time variants of my ViewModels and bind them to my Views. But I never thought of doing this at a more detailed level. I will give this a try.

Comment: Also see my article http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=958, section "Always use typed XAML bindings"

Comment: Updated link: https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/

Comment: Visual studio 2019 (without ReSharper) still unable to find the bound properties in XAML when executing "Find all reference" or "Rename" after applying this solution.